# How to restrict display menu items on right click on nsoutline view for Few rows only?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview, menuitem, nsoutlineview

I have a `NSOutlineView` and i need to display menu items on right click of row. method `ValidateMenuItem` gets called on displaying menu.But i want to restrict few rows to display menu items.

How to achieve this please help.

Comment: just saw old posts.... simple answer for this would be, we have to programmatically decide from ValidateMenu . to display menu or not we can maintain bool value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just saw old posts.... simple answer for this would be, we have to programmatically decide from ValidateMenu . to display menu or not we can maintain bool value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit NSOutlineview class and override 'menuForEvent' 
   `- (NSMenu *)menuForEvent:(NSEvent *)event`
and based on your logic you can return the menu you wanted to display else return nil. Then you need to use this inherited outlineview wherever needed.